# Scrollview not working?

Tags: android, xml, layout, scrollview, android-linearlayout

In my code scrollview is not working. When I directly call this layout scrollview works fine.But when I call this layout from another view this layout is not scrollable.

```
           <ScrollView                
             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@+id/scrollData"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:fillViewport="true"
             android:background="#000">
             <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:background="@color/setting_back">           
            <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/about"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="70dip" 
             android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
             android:background="@drawable/background_with_shadow">
         <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/star"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:text="@string/fa_star"
                    android:textColor="#3a3a3a"
                    android:textSize="30sp"/>
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/about_id"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="About"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/fa_angle_down_about"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="right"
                            android:text="@string/fa_angle_down"
                            android:textColor="#3a3a3a"
                            android:textSize="30sp"/>
             </LinearLayout>        
      </LinearLayout> 
      <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/slide_down_about"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
         android:padding="10dp"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:background="#fff">
            <TextView  
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:text="@string/about_content"/>
            </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout 
         android:id="@+id/feedback"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="70dip" 
         android:background="@drawable/background_with_shadow">
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/bell"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:text="@string/fa_feedback"
                    android:textColor="#3a3a3a"
                    android:textSize="30sp"/>
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/feedback_id"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="Feedback"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/fa_angle_down_feedback"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="right"
                            android:text="@string/fa_angle_down"
                            android:textColor="#3a3a3a"
                            android:textSize="30sp"/>
             </LinearLayout>
      </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/slide_down_feedback"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
         android:padding="10dp"
         android:background="#fff">
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:background="#DBDFE2"
                android:orientation="vertical">
            <EditText   
                    android:id="@+id/submitfeedback"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:background="#fff"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:hint="Your feedback here..."
                    android:textColor="#000000" 
                    android:textColorHint="#ccc"
                    />
            <Button 
                    android:id="@+id/submit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:background="#de682c"
                    android:text="submit"/>
            </LinearLayout>
       </LinearLayout>        
      <LinearLayout 
         android:id="@+id/terms"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="70dip" 
         android:background="@drawable/background_with_shadow">
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/comment"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:text="@string/fa_terms"
                    android:textColor="#3a3a3a"
                    android:textSize="30sp"/>
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/terms_id"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="Terms of use"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/fa_angle_down_terms"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="right"
                            android:text="@string/fa_angle_down"
                            android:textColor="#3a3a3a"
                            android:textSize="30sp"/>
             </LinearLayout>
      </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/slide_down_terms"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
         android:padding="10dp"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

                  android:background="#fff">

                   <TextView     
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:text="@string/about_content"/>
      </LinearLayout>     
      <LinearLayout 
         android:id="@+id/privacy_policy"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="70dip" 
         android:background="@drawable/background_with_shadow">
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/license"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:text="@string/fa_policy"
                    android:textColor="#3a3a3a"
                    android:textSize="30sp"/>
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/policy_id"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="Privacy Policy"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/fa_angle_right_down_policy"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="right"
                            android:text="@string/fa_angle_down"
                            android:textColor="#3a3a3a"
                            android:textSize="30sp"/>
             </LinearLayout>
      </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/slide_down_policy"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
         android:padding="10dp"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:background="#fff">
            <TextView           
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:text="@string/about_content"/>
       </LinearLayout>    
 </LinearLayout> 
 </ScrollView>
```

I tried all solution from Stackoverflow.

Comment: what do you mean with directly and with another layout

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan, how you are calling from another view ? Are you using `<include>`

Comment: @Tasneem i am not calling :D

Comment: @ Aditya Vyas-Lakhan ,Directly means calling from MainActivity which appears first and with another layout means calling from other than mainactivity.

Answer (score 2):

Where is the closing tag of scrollView ? 
maybe because of this scrollView not working

Comment: close tag is there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollData"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:background="#000"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/setting_back">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/about"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background_with_shadow">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/star"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:text="@string/fa_star"
                android:textColor="#3a3a3a"
                android:textSize="30sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/about_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="About"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fa_angle_down_about"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:text="@string/fa_angle_down"
                    android:textColor="#3a3a3a"
                    android:textSize="30sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/slide_down_about"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="#fff">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="@string/about_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/feedback"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dip"
            android:background="@drawable/background_with_shadow">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bell"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:text="@string/fa_feedback"
                android:textColor="#3a3a3a"
                android:textSize="30sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/feedback_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="Feedback"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fa_angle_down_feedback"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:text="@string/fa_angle_down"
                    android:textColor="#3a3a3a"
                    android:textSize="30sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/slide_down_feedback"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="#fff">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:background="#DBDFE2"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/submitfeedback"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:background="#fff"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:hint="Your feedback here..."
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textColorHint="#ccc"
                    />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/submit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:background="#de682c"
                    android:text="submit"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/terms"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dip"
            android:background="@drawable/background_with_shadow">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/comment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:text="@string/fa_terms"
                android:textColor="#3a3a3a"
                android:textSize="30sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/terms_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="Terms of use"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fa_angle_down_terms"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:text="@string/fa_angle_down"
                    android:textColor="#3a3a3a"
                    android:textSize="30sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/slide_down_terms"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

            android:background="#fff">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="@string/about_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/privacy_policy"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dip"
            android:background="@drawable/background_with_shadow">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/license"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:text="@string/fa_policy"
                android:textColor="#3a3a3a"
                android:textSize="30sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/policy_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="Privacy Policy"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fa_angle_right_down_policy"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:text="@string/fa_angle_down"
                    android:textColor="#3a3a3a"
                    android:textSize="30sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/slide_down_policy"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="#fff">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="@string/about_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put your layout between `ScrollView` tag when you are including this layout in another layout. That would work.

in your other layout:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/your_scrollview_layout"/>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, make a bundle like this to get scrollable..

```
<ScrollView                
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/scrollData"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:fillViewport="true"
     android:background="#000">

     <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- PUT YOUR CONTENT/ ELEMENT IN HERE -->

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: `LinearLayout` inside `ScrollView` should have `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` instead of `match_parent`. It should  not match ScrollView's height. Instead it has height which is sum of heights of its children - and provides that height to ScrollView to understand how to scroll.

Comment: sorry - can you add this in tag ScrollView : 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"